# Кастомные маркеры в индексированном чарте

Tags: c#, winforms, диаграммы

Помогите с решением. Имеем чарт с мультисерией. Все до боли примитивно: ось х время, ось y - value. Точки чарта проиндексированы чтобы несколько серий корректно отображались в одной ChartArea. Дискретность оси времени минуты. 
Серии между собой выравнены. Это значит, что в каждой серии равное количество DataPoint.
И есть информация **для каждой серии** что допустим в 17:43:11 произошло некоторое событие. Необходимо на график серии в этом месте установить маркер/крестик/метку (что нибудь) чтобы это выглядело как на втором моем скрине. При индексированных рядах (сериях) Добавление поинта ломает график. т.е. по логике это должны быть не дата поинты а некие кастомные маркеры и обрабатываться они должны в

`private void chart1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e){ }`

т.е. наносится сверху серии после отрисовки. 
Или есть еще какой либо другой способ? Подскажите кто делал похожее.
Или еще один вариант не индексировать серии, добавить эти кастомные датапоинты с индивидуальной отрисовкой, тогда я не знаю как их выровнять между собой(

текущий чарт
[image: текущий чарт]
а так нужно
[image: Как должно быть]

Comment: Уточните какую библиотеку вы используете для построения графиков.

Comment: это MSChart стандартный компонент Windows Forms